# Android Sharedpreference Check if the user already logged in or not

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I want to check if the user is logged in or not by checking if Their ID is `null` or not.
if the ID is `null` then start `loginActivity`, if not then carry on.

I make a separate class for my sharedpreference and have imported it, declared it.
however the program returned Nullpointer Error when I run it. My intention was exactly to check whether the string `id` is null or not.

FYI : at the moment, there is no user logged in, so the App should run the LoginActivity becauase getMyID() should return null and therefore run the condition

Please tell me where did I make mistake and how should I do it instead

**my setter and getter for ID in sharedpreference :**

```
public void setMyID(String myID) {
    editor.putString(MYUSERID, myID);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getMyID() {
    return pref_global.getString(MYUSERID, null);
}
```

**This is my mainactivity file**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setTitle("Selamat Datang");

myContext = this;
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(myContext);

checkLoginState();

}

public void checkLoginState(){
    if(prefManager.getMyID() == null ){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: public String getMyID() {
    return pref_global.getString(MYUSERID, "");
}

Answer (score 0):

I think default value parameter of `getString(MYUSERID, "default value")` is non null type, you just need to set it to another non null string. Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

When pulling data from sharedPreferences, you can try entering "" instead of entering the default value as null. I am sharing the sample code below;

```
public String getMyID() {
   return pref_global.getString(MYUSERID, "");
}


public void checkLoginState(){
if(prefManager.getMyID() == ""){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

}